Load dependencies from different folder after publishing .NET
I have a project that has some dependencies installed via NuGet. I want those dependencies to live in a folder called dependencies/ after being built with dotnet publish. I want to tell my executable to load them from that folder. I am using .NET 8
I have tried using AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += MyHandler, where MyHandler would correct the path and load it, however that didn't work as the loading of assemblies occured before my piece of code even though it is at the top of Main in Program.cs.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

doesnt additionalProbingPaths in runtimeconfig.json work?

You have to slow down the just-in-time compiler.  Move the critical code from Main() into another static method and decorate that method with [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]

Dang, I was looking at runtimeconfig.json but couldn't find that paramater anywhere. With that I get the error An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (x.deps.json) was not found ...
However, the solution from @HansPassant worked perfectly! If you wish you can make an Answer so I can put it as solved.
Thank you both very much, I appreciate your help.

Using the solution that Hans Passan posted in the comments solved it for me.
The comment:

You have to slow down the just-in-time compiler. Move the critical code from Main() into another static method and decorate that method with [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]

